# Email inline image in email not working on MacOS email

Tags: java, image, email, spring-boot

I'm sending HTML emails from java, using spring boot. Emails include signature with image logo of our firm. It works perfectly fine f.e. on gmail. But in MacOS app Email the logo is sent as attachment and is not inlined.

Non-related parts of code replaced by ...

```
final Locale locale = ...;
final MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper;
try {
    helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true, "UTF-8");
    helper.setTo(...);
    helper.setCc(...);
    helper.setBcc(...);
    helper.setFrom(...);

    final String htmlContent = templateEngine.process(..., new Context(locale, ...));
    helper.setText(htmlContent, true);
    helper.addInline("myImg", new ClassPathResource(".../myImg.png"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MessagingException e) {
    throw new MailSendException(..., e);
}
javaMailSender.send(mail);
```

HTML is generated by thymeleaf and is following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
...
<img src=".../myImg.png" th:src="'cid:' + ${'myImg'}" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the code of this extension [Spring Boot Email Tools](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools), where maybe you can find a better way to create emails.

Personally, I think that you may save some time if you use it directly to send emails via the `EmailService` bean. From the docs (the example is based on Freemarker template engine):

```
@Autowired
public EmailService emailService;

public void sendEmailWithTemplating(){
   Arrays.asList(new Cospirator("cassius@sic-semper.tyrannis", "Gaius Cassius Longinus"),
            new Cospirator("brutus@sic-semper.tyrannis", "Marcus Iunius Brutus Caepio"))
        .stream.forEach(tyrannicida -> {
       final Email email = DefaultEmail.builder()
            .from(new InternetAddress("divus.iulius@mala-tempora.currunt", "Gaius Iulius Caesar"))
            .to(Lists.newArrayList(new InternetAddress(tyrannicida.getEmail(), tyrannicida.getName())))
            .subject("Idus Martii")
            .body("")//Empty body
            .encoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).build();
        //Defining the model object for the given Freemarker template
        final Map<String, Object> modelObject = new HashMap<>();
        modelObject.put("tyrannicida", tyrannicida.getName());

       emailService.send(email, "idus_martii.ftl", modelObject);
   };
}

private static class Cospirator {
  private String email;
  private String name;
  public Cospirator(final String email, final String name){
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
  }

  //getters
}
```

The dependencies you need are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-thymeleaf-email</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Pretty convenient, ain't it?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Don't think it will save me any coding atm, but if it works...

Comment: Well, so I've tried it with no success. Ended up with org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter'. I mean... I probably could get that work after a while, but I'd rather have it standard spring way, using the code I posted (it probably will be just some small addition). I don't see added value of Spring Boot Email Tools. The code isn't really "neater" :/

Comment: I think that you made a bad settings, it seems you are using the persistence layer, that is optional according with the docs. You should set the following properties: `spring.mail.persistence.enabled: false
spring.mail.persistence.redis.embedded: false
spring.mail.persistence.redis.enabled: false`. Anyway, how to solve the issue I think that is all up to you